# Splunk configuration for dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, splunk

How do I configure log4net to push log message to splunk? I am using dot net 4.6 version. I have searched google a lot and not able to find any configuration for framework 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options based on the logging output you are producing(Syslog?).

You might need to send it to Syslog logging server that is already Splunk connected, or install a Splunk Universal Forward(UF) to pick the logs up from your specific location, for instance:

`./splunk add monitor /var/log`

and [point the UF to your Splunk Indexers](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/8.0.2/Forwarder/Configureforwardingwithoutputs.conf), for example:

```
[tcpout:<target_group>]
server= <ipaddress_or_hostname_of_receiving_server1>:<receving_open_port>, <receiving_server2>, ...
```

Comment: does it help or answer your question?